# How to properly DumpSave & Get Global`s symbols inside packages while not touching Global context?

Tags: evaluation, export, import, packages, symbols

For efficiency reasons I prefer to use `DumpSave` instead of `Save`.

For ease of access I prefer to save symbols in `DumpSaved` files inside Global` context.

But when my code evolved and I moved it inside packages I found a lot of problems to read symbols from those `DumpSaved` files so that read & write process

- allows for use saved variables inside my package (and its context)
- does not affect variables in `` Global` ``
- When user loads the file directly with `Get`, bypassing my package (and perhaps not even loading it), the symbol is available in `` Global` `` context for him or her
- symbol name is not hard-coded into function (but of course it must hard-coded into the file itself :-( )

Simply put: I want to use `DumpSave` & `Get` the way I use `Export` & `Import`, but with efficiency and flexibility benefits.

I come up with the following code, but it still messes the Global context and has the symbol name hardcoded (`` Global`myglobalname ``):

```
SaveMySymbol[object_,path_String]:= Block[{},
   OwnValues[Global`myglobalname] = HoldPattern[Global`myglobalname] :> object;
   DumpSave[
    path<>".mx", Global`myglobalname]];

LoadMySymbol[path_String]:= Block[{strfullpath},
  strfullpath = path<>".mx";
  If[FileExistsQ[strfullpath], Get[strfullpath]; Global`myglobalname,
    Null]]
```

I guess the problem with messing the `` Global` `` context can be avoided by caching the maybe existing definition of `` Global`myglobalname `` symbol and returning it back after `Get`. But the code look already awfully complex (it took me a full day to figure out the trick with `OwnValues`) and I suspect that *there must be an easy way*... Well, so far there always was one with Mathematica...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  Your question alludes to and then disallows some possible solutions.  Would you consider using a context other than ``Global` `` for example?

Comment: If possible not. With different symbols' context the answer would be trivial, but I prefer to lay it in Global` for ease of debugging. I've updated the problem statement to avoid confusion.

Comment: Have you tested and ruled out all options described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/121)?

Comment: All ruled out. I specifically need DumpSave. It is a huge amount of data, and it takes over 200MB and a few minutes to write it in this optimizied format.

Comment: Is it the saving or loading that you find slow?  Also, have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36/121) yet?

Comment: Yes. Especially loading is of an order of magnitude slower. What I load are some EEG data, but they are not plain - they have some object-oriented structure. (Actually they are imported from the R through MathLink. Since the import takes awfully long, I decided to store my working objects with DumpSave). I think that once the problem is solved, it might be a useful idiom (if only one is not concerned with portability). And Mr. Wizard - I appreciate your open-mindness in finding the solution.

Comment: I don't use `DumpSave` any more because it saves the symbol names together with their definitions, and it's a pain to manage that.  Symbols names from the MX might conflict with existing ones, and if you forget what the symbols names were, it's not that convenient to retrieve them.  Why don't you just use `Export` and `Import`?  It works fine with MX files (the DumpSave format), but it doesn't save symbol names.  `Export["data.mx", data, "MX"]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs It is a different paradigm. We already discussed this in comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247005/efficiently-working-with-and-generating-large-text-files/8250860#8250860), where I tried to describe the circumstances where using `DumpSave` with named symbols is actually advantageous. Basically, if you choose your own (particularly OO-style, and stateful ones,  e.g. classes / structs) data structures over built-in ones, using `DumpSave` has advantages.

Comment: @Leonid That's true, but data structures like that are quite advanced and not commonly used...  It honestly seems to me that here all the problems of the OP stem from the difference between `DumpSave` and `Export` and maybe he is just *not aware* that `Export` can be just as fast as `DumpSave`

Comment: I was just unaware of this simple fact... I assumed, that if it was possible, it would be mentioned in documentation of DumpSave. So I didn't really check it. And well, I've been using Mathematica for over 10 years...

Comment: @Szabolcs You may be right. It is not clear to what extent the OP needs state / defined symbols...Ok, the situation gor resolved while I was writing the comment :)

Comment: @Adam I can say the same, yet I only learned about this last year!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To show how this is possible:

> Simply put: I want to use `DumpSave` & `Get` the way I use `Export` &
>   `Import`, but with efficiency and flexibility benefits.

You can simply use `Import` and `Export`.  They do support the same format that `DumpSave` uses, and they give you the same performance.  But they don't save symbol names.

```
Export["data.mx", data, "MX"]

data = Import["data.mx"]
```

MX files are not portable between architectures though, so you may consider using `Compress`ed strings, as [described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1960/12).  This is several times slower, but it's still quite fast compared to any other alternative and it's portable.

If you ever need to save `InterpolatingFunction`s, [please be aware of this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3293/how-to-fix-broken-interpolatingfunction).