# Transfer of symbols between contexts

Tags: syntax, symbols, contexts

As many others (I guess) I'm struggling with the handling of contexts within Mathematica. I'm working on a new package definition with the usual syntaxt specified by the Mathematica documentation:

```
BeginPackage["example`"];

<Entry Points>

Begin["`Private`"]

<Definitions>

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

Now I want to use symbols generated in another Notebook and saved with DumpSave for efficiency. The code in this other Notebook is thus

```
DumpSave[<some mx file>,{symbol1,symbol2,...,symboln}]
```

when I import these symbols into my package it looks like this:

```
BeginPackage["example`"];

<Entry Points>

Begin["`Private`"]

DumpGet[<some mx file>];
<Definitions>

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

there is already the catch: The Symbols are not automatically loaded into the private context of the package (which is example`Private` in the above code snippet) but into the original context of the Notebook where the mx file has been generated (which is Global` in my case)! Thus I need to convert the symbols either into the private context in the package definition (which would the following statements

```
example`Private`symbol1=Global`symbol1;
example`Private`symbol2=Global`symbol2;
.
.
.
example`Private`symboln=Global`symboln;
Remove[Global`symbol1,Global`symbol2,...,Global`symboln])
```

or save the symbols already into the right context by using

```
example`Private`symbol1=symbol1;
example`Private`symbol2=symbol2;
.
.
.
example`Private`symboln=symboln;
DumpSave[<some mx file>,{example`Private`symbol1, example`Private`symbol2, 
  ..., example`Private`symboln}]
```

in the generating Notebook (which would be my preferred solution).
I need to do all of this clumsy setup because I do not want to have the symbols in the Global` context because then the symbols are visible outside of the package, which is not necessary and may cause shadowing problems too.
Now my question: Is there a quick way to copy symbols over from one context into another? Something like

```
Set[Evaluate[example`Private`#],Global`#]&/@{symbol1,symbol2,...,symboln}
```

would be preferrable. However above statement does not work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7912984/618728, [(19902)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19902/121), [(3378)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3378/121)

Comment: A simple question: why do you need to load definitions from an MX file in your package?  Wouldn't it be better to put everything in plain text and then save the complete package as a .MX file if loading speed is important?

Comment: Second question: you show copying definitions e.g. ``example`Private`symbol1 = Global`symbol1;`` -- why not simply change the Context to ``example`Private` `` before you define those symbols in the first place?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard question 1: I'm using a Notebook with the autogenerated package option to define the package contents. I prefer this method because the package code is much better readable, because of the excellent formatting possibilities for Notebooks compared to .m files. Furthermore what goes into the package can be easily defined through the initialization cell flag. However the parameters I'm talking about are interpolation statements which are generated with a lot of data-crunching from measured data where I simply do not want to burden the package definition with, just for size reasons.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard question 2: Fair point. I initially used XML files for the transfer of the symbols and there the context is not preserved (Importing symbols from XML files just read in the short form of the symbol name and thus drop the context definition). However with the growing amout of XML files the Import run time increased too. Thus I was forced to switch over to .mx files. Since there are numerous symbols to export/import I would need to correct the context at multiple positions in the Notebook. Change it at one place (at the export) seemed to me the more efficient way.

Comment: It sounds like you are loading data rather than function definitions.  In that case why not load your data anonymously (as in not assigned to symbols) and then process it inside the package and make assignments as necessary.  Also, have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/121)?  You can also `Export` data as a `MX` file.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: O.k. I give up, the main reason of splitting up the definitions across a Notebook and a package was to reduce the initialization time of the package, since the data involves a lot of Interpolation statements on data tables. Now I just save the interpolation statements within the package into an mx file, and read them in again when the package is initialized. Thus there is no problem with contexts and the initialization is still quick. I'll post an explanation as an answer soon....

Comment: This sounds like the exact use-case of ``Context[symbol] = "context`"``, c.f. e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78926/why-is-a-symbol-still-found-after-changing-its-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem now differently. According to my last comment to my question I now just save the interpolation statements within the package into an mx file

```
DropFileExtension[datafile_] :=StringJoin[Riffle[Most[StringSplit[datafile, "."]], "."]];
DumpMX[datafile_, symbol_: dummy] := Module[{filename},
  filename =DropFileExtension[datafile] <> "_" 
    <>StringReplace[$System, " " -> ""] <> "_" 
    <> ToString[NumberForm[$VersionNumber, {2, 1}]] <> ".mx";
  If[! MatchQ[FindFile[filename], $Failed], 
    DeleteFile[filename]];(*Delete File if it is already existing*)
    symbol = ReadMX[datafile, True];
    DumpSave[filename, symbol];
  ];

ReadMX::MXFileError = "MX file `1` of optical database not found.";
ReadMX[datafile_, symbol_: dummy] := Module[{filename, fields},
 filename = DropFileExtension[datafile] <> "_" 
   <> StringReplace[$System, " " -> ""] <> "_" 
   <> ToString[NumberForm[$VersionNumber, {2, 1}]] <> ".mx";
 If[MatchQ[FindFile[filename], $Failed], 
   Message[ReadMX::MXFileError, filename], Import[filename]];
 Return[symbol];
 ];
]
```

Any symbol (defined default globally as dummy) is saved into an MX file including the System and Mathematica Version information (since the binary MX file is not transferrable between different systems and versions) in the name.

```
DumpMX["test.mx",dummy]
```

and can be read by

```
ReadMX["test.mx",dummy]
```

.