# LinearSolveFunction unusable if stored to disk?

Tags: linear-algebra

I encounter a problem when saving a `LinearSolveFunction` to disk, where the LinearSolveFunction is obtained with `LinearSolve` for a non-square matrix. If I read the function object from disk, it can no longer be applied to an array.

For example:

```
In[1]:= a = LinearSolve[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
In[2]:= a >> "tst.m";
In[3]:= b = << "tst.m";
```

At this point, `a===b` and the displayed `FullForm` of a and b are equal. However:

```
In[4]:= a[{0, 0, 0}]
Out[4]= {0, 0}

In[5]:= b[{0, 0, 0}]
Out[5]= LinearSolveFunction[{3,2},{2,False,{{{1,0},{0,1},{1,0}}},{0,Automatic,Automatic},0}][{0,0,0}]
```

I am using Mathematica 8.0.4 (64bit) on Linux.

Is this a bug ? Is there a good workaround ? Of course, I could avoid caching the `LinearSolve` result altogether and save only the matrix to be "inverted".

Comment: I think I had a similar issue with `InterpolatingFunction` a while back, and I think I moved on without an answer

Comment: Your first line returns an error (matrix not square).

Comment: Related: [How to fix broken InterpolatingFunction?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3293/121)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a bug. Evaluating

```
a = LinearSolve[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
```

gives a message:

```
LinearSolve::sqmat1: "The matrix {{1,0},{0,1},{1,0}} is not square so a factorization will not be saved."
```

which states that the factorization will not be saved. So, once you apply `b` to the vector there is not factorization that can be used to solve this. Note that this is not an issue with square matrices.

Comment: It still seems a bit like a bug.  Why can't it be written to the file?  Why does a[{0, 0, 0}] give an answer when b[{0, 0, 0}] does not?

Comment: @Jason, because there is no factorization in b. This is not a bug. One may in a future version extend this, though. If you'd like that it might be a good idea to file a suggestion with the tech support.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Of course, the warning indicates that it doesn't precompute a factorization as it would for the rectangular case. However, I can't find a restriction for the applicability to  non-rectangular matrices in the documentation. Indeed, it _does_ work if everything is kept in memory. There appears to be some internal difference between a `LinearSolveFunction` returned by LinearSolve and one read in from disk, which is not visible at the `FullForm` level. I don't see why this should not be considered a bug.

Comment: I agree. I think that, at a minimum, the documentation should be improved.

Comment: The documentation does mentions this: ref/LinearSolveFunction. I field this as a suggestion for future improvement, but can not say when/if an extension will be implemented.