# Are FEM methods integrated in NDSolve yet?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

About a year ago there was [a discussion on these forums](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-is-ndsolvefem) as to whether FEM methods have already been integrated into `NDSolve` in *Mathematica*. The answer back then was that `` NDSolve`FEM `` was just an internal context in *Mathematica* 8 without any further use.

My question now: Has this changed in version 9, i.e. is there any FEM functionality integrated into *Mathematica* now?

Comment: You'll have to wait for @ruebenko for a definitive answer (if he's not under NDA about this, as many WRI employees are for planned future functionality), but I think the answer is no--this is still a work in progress. As I understand it, the goal is to use it to solve general PDEs and implement a PDE analog of the `DifferentialRoot` object. Unsurprisingly, this ambitious project may take a while to complete.

Comment: @Wizard, there is no FEM in `NDSolve` in Version 9 and it's unclear when such a method is fully implemented in `NDSolve`. I am under a NDA and not allowed to comment on future versions of Mathematica. Sorry I can not be more concrete here. If you which for such a Method, I'd suggest writing to tech support - such customer requests will help prioritize projects like a build in FEM.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate since the answer has not changed since the last question. I think it will be announced quite clearly when the feature is finally available, but nobody can say anything about it until then, so further questions on this topic don't seem to serve any purpose.