# How to apply Robin boundary condition in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, finite-difference-method

Robin condition is the boundary condition which combines the Dirichlet and Neumann condition at the same boundary.

For example:

At the boundary `x = 0` to `2`: I want to apply

`u[x] = 0` for `x = 0 to 1`
and `du/dx = 0` for `x = 1 to 2`.

I think one of the possible approach is reformulate the PDE discretization using the finite difference method, and manual apply the Robin boundary condition on the systems of ODE.

Could we trick that for `DSolve`, `NDSolve`?

Comment: THere is a notebook here that has an example http://www.ekayasolutions.com/UCDMath/PDEApplications.php  (using finite difference).

Comment: btw, I just looked at your B.C. (before I just saw you mentioned Robin BC in title.) the B.C. you show is not Robin. In Robin, BOTH  Dirichlet and Neumann exist on the same region. What you have above is really a mixed B.C. and not Robin. btw, wait a little bit for Version 10, hopefully it will have finite elements support finally and one can expect to solve these problems much easier with FEM new API

Comment: Thank you Nasser. I also look at your demonstration. It's great. Are you sure that FEM will be implemented in v10? :) For this piece-wised boundary condition do you know how to trick Mathematica?

Comment: IMTEK FEM is also great but few peoples use it. I dont understand why.

Comment: I am just guessing really that FEM will be in V 10. Only someone in WRI would know for sure. But if you type ?"NDSolve`FEM`*"  you'll see all the hooks there. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-is-ndsolvefem (its been there since V8, so one would expect it is ready by now :)

Comment: IMTEK is great, but it hasn't been update for a long time, some of its functions are not compatible with current mma version now...

Comment: @Nasser I didn't have high hopes based on that context, as you say it's been there for a long time.  But take a look under Geometry [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/).  It looks encouraging.  Most of it is missing though.

Comment: @Silvia , which fe tools are recommaned now (sure in MMA)?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Finite element method is built-in now. Check [the documentations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/guide/FiniteElementMethodGuide.html) for details.