# Solution of electromagnetic wave in frequency domain seems strange

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, finite-element-method, electromagnetics

**Bug introduced in 10, fixed in 11.1.**

---

I want to solve the electromagnetic wave equation in frequency domain. A known solution, a plane wave  `Exp[ I k0 x]` is used to set the Dirichlet conditions to all the boundaries. I expect to get the plane wave solution. The following code runs well ,but the result is strange. I don't know why. It seems  high-frequency oscillation occurs. Is there some options to eliminate the unusual oscillation?
thanks a lot!

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`  

λ = 0.53; k0 = 2 π/λ; R = λ;

mesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, R}, {0, R}}, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005];

mesh["Wireframe"]

op = 
  Most[Curl[Curl[{u[x, y], v[x, y], 0}, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] - 
   k0^2 {u[x, y], v[x, y], 0}]

pde = op == {0, 0};

Subscript[Γ, D] = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == Exp[I k0 x]}, True];

{us, vs} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pde, Subscript[Γ, D]}, {u, v}, {x, y} ∈ mesh]

DensityPlot[Re[vs[x, y]], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code posted does not produce any errors when evaluated. There does not seem to be any question to answer.

Comment: The question is probably:  "Why does this output not agree with the known analytical solution $v(x,y) = e^{ik_0x}$ and $u(x,y) = 0$?"

Comment: I don't have a complete solution yet, but here are my thoughts:  (1)  the "high-frequency" oscillation is at the "frequency" of the mesh you're using.  Reducing `MaxCellMeasure` alleviates this.  (2) Solving the equation $\nabla^2 v = -k_0^2 v$ (which should be equivalent to the above equations as long as $\partial u/\partial x + \partial v/\partial y = 0$) yields a well-behaved result.  If I have time, I'll come back to this later.

Comment: Thank you, I have made a mistake. For a electromagnetic wave , Div(E)==0 should satisfied.  To solve Helmholtz equation is the correct choice.

Comment: My first attempt is to simulate the propagation of electromagnetic wave in different media and seems got the answer by solve Laplacian[Bz]+k0^2*Bz==0,then got electric field by grad(Bz), but with low precision. So I try to solve the electric field directly but don't know how to add Div(E)==0 to the equations. I tried another method but got the complain of "nonlinear coefficient unsupported" , so low-level progamming may be unavoidable.

Comment: It seems to work if you replace  `Exp[I k0 x]` by `Cos[k0 x]` in the `DirickletCondition[...]`  ??

Comment: @andre Interesting, seems that trouble is made by the imaginary part of the boundary. Maybe you can make this into an answer?

Comment: @xzczd I don't dare to  do an answer because my ideas are not enough clear about this (on the theorical point of view). Feel free do it (or someone else).

Comment: As I understand it, the code works well in 13.0.0.

Answer (score 9):

## Update

OP's code produces the correct result since *v11.1*, I think it's safe to say the "noisy" result is caused by a bug.

---

Here's a solution based on finite difference method (FDM). The definition of `pdetoae` (a general purpose function discretizing PDE to algebraic equations with finite difference formula) can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871).

```
λ = 53/100; k0 = 2 π/λ; R = λ;

op = Most[Curl[Curl[{u[x, y], v[x, y], 0}, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] - 
    k0^2 {u[x, y], v[x, y], 0}];

pde = op == {0, 0};
bc = Function[{x, y}, {u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == Exp[I k0 x]}] @@@ {{0, y}, {R, y}, {x, 
      0}, {x, R}} // Flatten;

domain = {0, R};
points = 50;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 4;
(*Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this code piece,
  please find it in the link above. *)
ptoa = pdetoae[{u, v}[x, y], {grid, grid}, difforder];
del = Most@Rest@# &;

ae = del /@ del@# & /@ ptoa@pde;
aebc = MapAt[del, ptoa@bc, List /@ Range@4];
{b, mat} = CoefficientArrays[{ae, aebc} // Flatten, 
   Outer[#[#2, #3] &, {u, v}, grid, grid] // Flatten];
sollst = LinearSolve[-mat, N@b];
solmat = ArrayReshape[sollst, {2, points, points}];
{solu, solv} = ListInterpolation[#, {grid, grid}] & /@ solmat;

Outer[Plot3D[#@First[#2][x, y], {x, 0, R}, {y, 0, R}, PlotLabel -> #@Last@#2] &, {Re, 
   Im}, {{solu, "u"}, {solv, "v"}}, 1] // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Remark**

1. Number of grid points i.e. `points` should be **even**, or the error of $\text{Im}(v)$ will be quite large, I'm not sure about the reason.
2. Difference order i.e. `difforder` should be **even** and **greater than `2`**, or the error will be large and seems unlikely to be alleviated by increasing `points`. I guess this might explain why OP's code doesn't work well, because according to [this document page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#121815462), the default `"MeshOrder"` of `ToElementMesh` is exactly `2`, but since I'm still in *v9* and the Wolfram Cloud is too slow, I'd like to stop here.

Comment: Thank you! you code has help me to understand the EM wave equations better. Considering the ability to handle arbitrarily shaped regions I will continue to study FEM.